# uitableview does not reload to latest array, when text is typed in uisearchbar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

i am using the method to get venue from foursquare. and when i click to search bar to load the venue, it shows me the table minus one iteration, (for example if i search for "SAMSUNG" it reloads the tableview for "SAMSUN") but i can see from the nslog that that data is retrieved from four square and stored in nsarray, but it does not show in table.

```
- (void)getFourSquare:(NSString *)SearchString
{
NSString *CLIENT_ID = @"CLIENT_ID";
NSString *CLIENT_SECRET = @"CLIENT_SECRET";
NSString *searchString = SearchString;

NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=perth&intent=browse&radius=20000&limit=25&query=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=20140710",searchString,CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET];
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlString] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSArray *latestFSquares = [self fetchData:data];
        fsquares = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

        if (latestFSquares) {
            for (NSDictionary *fSquareDic in latestFSquares) {
                foursquare *fsquare = [[foursquare alloc] init];
                fsquare.name = [fSquareDic objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSLog(@"name : %@ ",[fSquareDic objectForKey:@"name"]);
                [fsquares addObject:fsquare];
            };
        }

    }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}];

  }
```

the method i am using to update the search text is below, i tried using the tableView reload in the below function and still shows me minus one iteration.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
[self getFourSquare:searchText];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line below

```
fsquares = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

You are creating new reference of `NSMutableArray` everytime, thats wrong. To fix this initialize `fsquares` once and change the values like below

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
     if(!fsquares)
         fsquares = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

     [self getFourSquare:searchText];    
}
```

And remove initialization inside the function `getFourSquare`.

**`Update`**

Move `[fsquares removeAllObjects]` to the following line in the below block

```
if (latestFSquares) {
    [fsquares removeAllObjects];
}
```

It should fix.

Cheers.

Comment: @IOSFeng Then most probably you are not getting data, and we are removing it, before it gets the search result, see my update I have moved the removeobjects function to when it gets the data to load.. It should work now..

Comment: its still completely blank, the question above loaded the uitableview, the problem was that it was not updating it to the complete search query. if i search for "SAMSUNG" it reloads the tableview for "SAMSUN"